# Connecting a Makita jigsaw (4351) to dry vacuum cleaner (Dyson)

Tags: dust, vacuum

Could someone share their experiences with connecting a Makita jigsaw (22mm vacuum piece) to a regular vacuum cleaner (Dyson)? It appears that some people say it's just really impractical to connect a jigsaw to a vacuum? I suspect it might be a good idea to get a longer hose that's a bit more flexible than the average vacuum hose. What say you?

Comment: Suitable hose reducers and duct tape should do fine.

Comment: Anything's possible with enough duct tape!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem with using something like a Dyson or any other "floor vac" is that their filters (and warranty) are not made for sucking up a stream of sawdust or other "shop dust".  I imagine you can, and it should work fine, but you could clog up a comparatively expensive filter in a short time.

A "shop vac" has large filters made for exactly this type of dust and the filters are pretty cheap and easy to replace.  Some shop vacs will also accept bags for certain very fine dust that would quickly clog a pleated filter.

Your other issue is that attachments for power tools are going to be made for the standard sizes of shop vac attachments.  The only thing the Dyson has to connect to is its own included tools so it might not fit anything else without a clunky adapter.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer!

Answer (score 6):

### It won't work well and you don't need it

1. A jig saw work doesn't create the same dust and mess problem like other woodworking tools such as a sander, router, skill saw, etc. A jig saw does not create the same small fine dust like particles and it just doesn't have the speed and power to throw them very far. High speed tools work by removing much smaller pieces during each passing cutting blade and as a byproduct creates a lot of dust and can throw all of it a long way. Sanders of course work by exclusively removing very fine particles
2. Collecting tool dust is about pulling a lot of air, to get the larger particles it needs to also be a powerful pull of air. A household vacuum clear, while it can 'suck' well for household cleaning work, just can't move enough volume of air. From experience you probably know that you must get the detachable tool very close to the surface to do much good or work it into an area where the air is channeled by the surrounding surfaces such that it's almost as if it were an extension of the vacuum attachment. For a jig saw it would not be possible to get the tool close enough to the tool head to pull in the particles without interfering with your field of view and work area and there is no confined area around the saw blade to assist with the air flow. Or alternately, if the vacuum port was at a good distance then it would not be able to do it's job due to lack of power and volume to get any dust. And certainly there isn't enough power to get the larger particles

If you want to keep the area clean, simply sweep or vacuum up afterwards, easy peasy. If you are doing a cut that somehow requires more attention to keeping the area from getting particles on it, simply hold or clamp the vacuum attachment near the work, on lower in height if sloped so that the particles will slide towards the opening. Or use an assistant whose job is to running the 'cleaning tool' as you work. If your concern is dust and breathing it, again, it just won't create much dust in the first place like other tools and is not a concern.

Comment: Thanks for that great answer! I feel bad that I cannot give two answers the correct answer mark.

Comment: it could sill get messy if you're cutting a dusty material like drywall.

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the dusty air go first through a cyclone filter which you will drive by your vacuum cleaner. Dust that the cyclone fails to capture will be trapped by the filter on the vacuum.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks! I came across those cyclone devices. I guess the cyclone devices has three openings. An inlet to the power tool, an outlet to the vacuum cleaner and then an opening for the dust with a bag (?) taped to it?

Comment: @Malte: It is not at all difficult to make your own device out of a bucket and scrap board that is almost as efficient at mechanical separation as one of those expensive plastic cyclone devices. See https://ericlippert.com/2013/11/26/thien-baffle/ for pictures of mine.

Comment: @Malte needs to be a rigid container rather than a bag otherwise it'll just collapse, and ideally at least as deep as the cyclone is high so the dust falls far enough away from the hole that it doesn't get get sucked into the vacuum if the hose gets blocked (at least for the off-the-shelf cyclones, Eric's baffle might not have that issue).

Comment: @EricLippert Awesome advice, ty! I was thinking of mounting a cyclone filter (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07L2XJJMF/) onto a some plastic container.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Thanks for pointing that out!